# Vercel (local) Serverless Functions with Vue3 returns js file body content?

Tags: vuejs3, serverless, vercel

I'm trying to add a function to my Vue3 app in Vercel. I was hoping to get it running locally using Vercel CLI (which seems to be running on vite).

I think I got it hosting locally just fine, however when I hit the function with axios and console.log the output I just get a dump of the file contents.

Node v20.10.0
NPM 10.2.3
Vercel CLI 32.7.2
Vue 3.2.0
Axios: 1.6.2

\vercel.json

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "*.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/((?!api).*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

\api\example.ts:

```js
import type { VercelRequest, VercelResponse } from "@vercel/node";

export default function handler(request: VercelRequest, response: VercelResponse) {
  const { name = "World" } = request.query;


  response.status(200).json({greeting: `Hello ${name}!`});
}
```

axios call:

```js
const helloWorld = async (name: string) => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3001/api",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const response = await api.get(`/example?name=${name}`);
  return response.data;
};

console.log(await helloWorld("Jim"));
```

Response:

[image]

I've searched the internet, tried different variations of the function export, looked through github issues... all to no avail.

It seems like most of the examples are doing SSR (not surprising giving Vercel's relationship with nextjs).

I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb.. but I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it hosted on vercel's servers with some fiddling (emptied vercel.json, troubleshooting env variables)

Looks like locally hosting vercel serverless functions is a known issue: https://github.com/magne4000/vite-plugin-vercel/issues/20

Here's a workaround: https://github.com/magne4000/vite-plugin-vercel/issues/19#issuecomment-1722198617